# Python Youtube ffmpeg Session Has Been Invalidated

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I get the following error while I'm playing YouTube audio with my bot

```
[tls @ 0000024ef8c4d480] Error in the pull function.
[matroska,webm @ 0000024ef8c4a400] Read error
[tls @ 0000024ef8c4d480] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

It seems like YouTube links expire? I don't really know but I need to fix this issue. This is my code:

```py
    class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

        def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
            super().__init__(source)
            self.requester = requester

            self.title = data['title']
            self.description = data['description']
            self.uploader = data['uploader']
            self.duration = data['duration']
            self.web_url = data['webpage_url']
            self.thumbnail = data['thumbnail']

        def __getitem__(self, item: str):
            return self.__getattribute__(item)

        @classmethod
        async def create_source(cls, ctx, player, search: str, *, loop, download=True):
            async with ctx.typing():
                loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
                to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
                raw_data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

                if 'entries' in raw_data:
                    # take first item from a playlist
                    if len(raw_data['entries']) == 1:
                        data = raw_data['entries'][0]
                    else:
                        data = raw_data['entries']
                        #loops entries to grab each video_url
                        total_duration = 0
                        try:
                            for i in data:
                                webpage = i['webpage_url']
                                title = i['title']
                                description = i['description']
                                uploader = i['uploader']
                                duration = i['duration']
                                thumbnail = i['thumbnail']
                                total_duration += duration

                                if download:
                                    source = ytdl.prepare_filename(i)
                                    source = cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=i, requester=ctx.author)
                                else:
                                    source = {'webpage_url': webpage, 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': title, 'uploader': uploader, 'description': description, 'duration': duration, 'thumbnail': thumbnail}

                                player.queue.append(source)

                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            return

                        embed=discord.Embed(title="Playlist", description="Queued", color=0x30a4fb, timestamp=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
                        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                        embed.set_thumbnail(url=data[0]['thumbnail'])
                        embed.add_field(name=raw_data['title'], value=f"{len(data)} videos queued.", inline=True)
                        embed.set_footer(text=raw_data["uploader"] + ' - ' + '{0[0]}m {0[1]}s'.format(divmod(total_duration, 60)))
                        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                        return

                embed=discord.Embed(title="Playlist", description="Queued", color=0x30a4fb, timestamp=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=data['thumbnail'])
                embed.add_field(name=data['title'], value=(data["description"][:72] + (data["description"][72:] and '...')), inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text=data["uploader"] + ' - ' + '{0[0]}m {0[1]}s'.format(divmod(data["duration"], 60)))
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

                if download:
                    source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
                else:
                    source = {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title'], 'uploader': data['uploader'], 'description': data['description'], 'duration': data['duration'], 'thumbnail': data['thumbnail']}
                    player.queue.append(source)
                    return

                source = cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)
                player.queue.append(source)


        @classmethod
        async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
            loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
            requester = data['requester']

            to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=True)
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

            return(cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester))
```

I'm using the rewrite branch of discord.py for the bot.
I'm not sure if I need to provide more details? Please let me know, I really need to get this fixed...

Comment: What is the length and quality of the audio you're trying to stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it isn't really a problem with your code (and many people complain of this error).

This is just a possible issue when *streaming* a video. If you absolutely want to stream it, you have to accept this as a potential issue. Note how (almost) every music bots set limitations for the video/music you want to listen to.

If you need to ensure you do not get this issue, you have to fully download the music. (Which will also make the bot loading longer before playing).

Comment: I see you answered your own question, can you elaborate on how you came to your conclusion?

And am I correct in reading it as saying that the issue is not with the link expiring but that YouTube is killing the connection because it believes your code to be a bot? If that is the case on what basis?

Comment: It wasn't my own question, I only edited it. It is not related to any "detection" of YouTube (though the usage of youtube_dl for the very purpose of streaming/downloading breaks Youtube terms of service).

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post all your code? i may have a solution for you if i was able to see the whole code.

the solution i would recomend is to download the soong and then delete it after.

You could set your download to true and then add this in your player_loop

```
            try:
            # We are no longer playing this song...so, lets delete it!
            with YoutubeDL(ytdlopts) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(source.web_url, download=False)
                filename = ydl.prepare_filename(info)
                try:
                    if os.path.exists(filename):
                        os.remove(filename)
                    else:
                        pass
                except Exception as E:
                    print(E)
            await self.np.delete()
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
```

bit botched but could be cleaned up, this was the best solution i have found for me.