# How do you suppress "Error in the pull function" messages to stdout?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am working on making my Discord bot into a music player using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/tree/7f41a598b3fba1bcab2817de64a08941200aa3c8). I got past the [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892635/discord-py-and-youtube-dl-read-error-and-the-session-has-been-invalidated-fo) of music being interrupted from an "Error in the pull function" by having ffmpeg reconnect upon this error. However, I cannot figure out how to suppress the error messages being sent to stdout anyway:

```
[tls @ 0000023ea3564e80] Error in the pull function.
[https @ 0000023ea3560d80] Will reconnect at 327680 in 0 second(s), error=I/O error.
```

My ytdl options and ffmpeg options are as follows:

```
YTDL_OPTIONS = \
{"format": "bestaudio",
 "noplaylist": True,
 "quiet": True}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = \
{"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5",
 "options": "-vn"}
```

I experimented with various YTDL options like `"no_warnings": False`, `"debug_printtraffic": False`, `"progress_hooks": []`, etc. However, none of these additions worked. To be honest, I don't even know the source of these messages (youtube-dl or discord.py itself). Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Comment: I've been having this same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using the [`ignoreerrors` flag](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/b286f201a8424e00cc91d27adcf53a5249b8a3b9/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L147).

Comment: Nothing changed. The bot already doesn't stop on download errors because of my `before_options` in `FFMPEG_OPTIONS`. The "Error in the pull function" and "Will reconnect at..." messages are still displayed despite the new `ignoreerrors` flag in `YTDL_OPTIONS`.