# Discord music bot's audio crashes

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.7

I'm trying to make a discord music bot, but for some reason, the audio just crashes.

Here's the code:

```py
# IMPORTING

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import urllib.request
import random
import re
import pafy


# VARIABLES
TOKEN = ""
BOT_PREFIX = "!"
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents=intents)


@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, *, args):

    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice or not voice.is_connected():
        await ctx.send("Don't think I am in a voice channel")
        return
    keywords = args.replace(" ", "+")
    html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+keywords)
    video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
    url = ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0])

    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL))

    video = pafy.new(url)
    if video.length >= 360:
        await ctx.send("The video you attempted to play was too long.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Now playing {video.title} on Youtube.")


# RUNNING THE BOT
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

After a bit, it just sends then error:
[tls @ 0x7f9fc1521a40] Error in the pull function.
[matroska,webm @ 0x7f9fc1808200] Read error
[tls @ 0x7f9fc1521a40] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
Last message repeated 1 times

How can I fix this without downloading the song?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139166/python-youtube-ffmpeg-session-has-been-invalidated ?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
# IMPORTING

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
import urllib.request
import random
import re
import pafy

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5",
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(description="joins a voice channel")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
            return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            vc = ctx.voice_client

    @commands.command(description="streams music")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=f"[{player.title}]({player.url}) [{ctx.author.mention}]")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(description="stops and disconnects the bot from voice")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

# VARIABLES
TOKEN = ""
BOT_PREFIX = "!"
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, intents=intents)
bot.add_cog(Music(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as:\n{0.user.name}\n{0.user.id}'.format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found.

Comment: @raid6n do you have your own join command? do you have 2 join commands in your code? what decorator are you using for your commands?

Comment: I just pasted your code and added the bot variable.

Comment: Could it be my version? My python version is 3.7.

Comment: @raid6n I think your version is fine. I'm not sure why the code isn't working. Are all your other commands working? Also, make sure you have `await bot.process_commands(message)` in your `on_message` event.

Comment: Also there's no on_message event?

Comment: @raid6n i've edited my answer to show you all the code you would need; just copy and paste it into your file and try it out.

Comment: Don't forget to copy-paste your token into the token variable

Comment: You edited it, I don't know what you changed, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: I just added the `on_message` event in which I wrote a line that would allow for commands to be processed from a user's message, so that your commands could run. No problem!